# How to exclude mvvm and other Nuget packages from code coverage, when analysing code coverage, using .runsettings file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

I am currently working on a group-project for school. All of my fellow students couldn't help me with the following problem.
When analysing the code coverage of out project, we wanted to exclude the c__DisplayClass.. This worked for us with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Exclude></Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
            <Functions>
              <Exclude>
                <Function>.*c__DisplayClass.*</Function>
              </Exclude>
            </Functions>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

After this I noticed that the code coverage analyses additional things like mvvm. :
https://i.ibb.co/Mn9rNzw/Screenshot-2019-01-14-at-12-47-05.png
(I can't upload images)

**Is it possible to exclude also the mvvm .dll files so we only check our own code?**

Thank you!